# Conflicting permission in provider hosted apps

Tags: office-365, user-profile-property, provider-hosted-app

I am stuck in a weird issue. I have a provider hosted app which needs to be deployed in MySite of users. This app is requesting for 2 permissions:

1. Full Control on Web (which only user can approve)
2. Read permission on User Profiles (which can be approved by tenant admin only).

   Both the permissions are necessary for the app. What is the proposed way of resolving this issue as there is no single person who can "Trust It"

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways that might work, though I haven't tried them:

1.) If the app is a Provider Hosted app, you might be able to use the "on the fly" permissions (user is redirected to special page at runtime to allow permissions ad hoc) to allow each MySite owner to grant access to their particular Web after a Site Collection admin has added the app to the top-level site collection for mysites.

2.) Although the users "My Site" appears to the user as a Web, I believe the "My Site" user is also a site collection admin for the site collection hosting their web.  You could have individual users install the app into their "My Site" site collection, and they can get prompted to "Allow Trust" for their app.